# Adding custom text to View Field type Single Line of Text not working

Tags: dynamics-crm, sandbox, powerapps

I am working with Dynamics and need to add custom url/text to a field via JScript.
I have tried

1. adding new Field creating its type as "Single line of text" and Format as "Url".
2. Attach the field to View with Custom Function webResource

But even adding a simple console message to the function in this field is not working.

Can someone make me understand how will it work?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Like @Guido mentioned, you cannot add that functionality in the views, basically, we are limited to add JS to display icons on the column, is this what you are trying to do? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/display-custom-icons-instead?view=op-9-1.  If you want to manage other columns in the form or attach it to the column's OnChange or the form's OnLoad, you'll have to do it from the form editor. Can you provide more details on what you need?

Answer (score 1):

That kind of approach is not the one you would use to add an event inside the form (what you wrote is used only if you want to add a webresource indicator beside the column inside a view), also the use of $(document).ready is not supported inside Dynamics, specific methods exist to interact with Dynamics UI.

There are several videos on youtube on how to start with javascript development for a Dynamics instance, you can check them.

Comment: Yeah I agree that it supports javascript and I got it that we cannot achieve customization of columns at view level.